# How to know the application loading time?

Tags: android

I have create an application that loads data into a list and then displays it on the mobile screen. My Application works perfect.

I want to fetch the time taken to load my application by Android OS. That is , when I click on the icon, starting from that point to when my list is ready to display on the screen.

Assume here list is displaying a country names from a static defined array. So nothing hard to do with that part.

I just want to know the time taken for loading the data to screen. Is there any way I can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can extend from `Application` and override the  `onCreate` method which is invoked when the Application first starts.

Description copied from class:

> Called when the application is starting, before any
>   activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers)
>   have been created. Implementations should be as quick as possible (for
>   example using lazy initialization of state) since the time spent in
>   this function directly impacts the performance of starting the first
>   activity, service, or receiver in a process. If you override this
>   method, be sure to call super.onCreate().

You can then measure time from here until the `Activity.onResume()`

You can customize the `Application` instance by declaring a custom name of the [Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)

Example:

```
m_startTick = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
// Load Something read from disk
Long n = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - m_startTick; // miliseconds
```